# How can I copy a formula down a column into every 3rd row?

Tags: excel

I want to copy the formula down the column, but only on every 3rd row. 
The formula I am using is: =CONCATENATE(A1," ",A2," ",A3)
and I want it to be copied into B1, B4, B7, B10, and so on... 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following steps will work, and can be easily extended to any sequence of blank and non-blank rows or columns.

1. Enter the formula into `B1`.
2. Select `B1:B3`, as shown below

   [image: Select B1:B3]
3. Drag the selection rectangle down three rows so that it covers`B1:B6`. You can drag it down by clicking and dragging on the small box in the bottom-right of the selection.

   [image: Drag Selection down]
4. The formula will only show up in `B4` only. You can repeat this for as long a sequence as you desire by dragging the selection box down further.

   [image: Completion]

Comment: Quick shortcut for very long sheets: You can **double click** the bottom right dot in the cell box to copy the formula downwards.

Answer (score 4):

A formula alternative for a very long list (where double-clicking the fill handle may be less tedious):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=1,A1&" "&A2&" "&A3,"")
```